# Add spring component to list overwrites component from the same type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

hi following the spring factory pattern ([following this great blog](http://kh-yiu.blogspot.be/2013/04/spring-implementing-factory-pattern.html))  I created a factory class

```
@Component
public interface FooFactory {
    Foo getFoo(String fooType);
}
public abstract class Foo {
    private Integer calc
    public Integer getCalc(){return calc}
    public void setCalc(Integer calc){
        this.calc = calc)
    }
}

@Component("bar")
public class Bar extends Foo  {

    @Overrride
    public void setCalc(Integer calc){
        this.calc = calc*10)
    }

    @Component("bazz")
        public class Bazz extends Foo  {
        @Override
        public void setCalc(Integer calc){this.calc = calc+10)
    }
}
```

in my main class

```
private List<Foo> createFoo(){
    List<Foo> fooList = ArrayList<Foo>(3)
    Foo bar1 = fooFactory.getFoo("bar")
    bar1.setCalc(10)
    Foo bar2 = fooFactory.getFoo("bar")
    bar2.setCalc(20)
    Foo bazz1 = fooFactory.getFoo("bazz")
    barzz1.setCalc(30)
    fooList.add(bar1)
    fooList.add(bar2)
    fooList.add(bazz1)

    for (Foo f:fooList)
        System.out.println(f.getCalc());
}
```

the result that I am getting is

```
200
200
40
```

and not as I expected

```
100
200
40
```

**which means that the first object in the list is overwritten by the second one from the same type. 
how can I solve that ?**

I do need to created them this way . because I actually add them to list at run time according to user input

> context xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean" id="fooFactory">
    <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="com.myname.FooFactory">
</property></bean>
```

Comment: Post your foo factory - the problem is there

Comment: Hi, foo factory is posted in my question (the first component) FooFactory.
if you mean the context xml than :
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean" id="fooFactory">
        <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="com.myname.FooFactory">
        </property></bean>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must annotate your beans with `@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`

```
@Component("bar")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Bar extends Foo  {
@Overrride
public void setCalc(Integer calc){this.calc = calc*10)
}


@Component("bazz")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Bazz extends Foo  {
@Override
public void setCalc(Integer calc){this.calc = calc+10)
```

}

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html

> ServiceLocatorFactoryBean...They will typically be used for prototype beans, i.e. for factory methods that are supposed to return a new instance for each call.

Answer (score 1):

[andresoviedo's answer is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544495/280244)

some more explanation:

The [`ServiceLocatorFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html) is just an proxy of the normal bean factory. 
Therefore the prototype/singleton scope is handled in the same way as it is for normal injection.

So when you expect Prototype scope beans (that is what you expect (two beans of the same type with different values)), you need to configure that the beans are of this scope. So you need to add `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` to your two bean.